# Ruby-Proper Usage of the Date.step() method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

I have been trying to use the step() method on Date object to retrieve the previous 2 dates from the current date as follows:

```
  date_d.step(2, step=-2){|d|
    puts d        
  }
```

where 2 is the limit and step is the number of steps backward or forward.

I have done this in accordance with the Documentation given here: [Date.step()](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/date/rdoc/classes/Date.html#M000195)

This code snippet goes into an infinite loop and then outputs the date non-stop (backwards)

There doesn't seem to be enough documentation for this method and i am not finding solutions online as well.

Please help me out with this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the limit parameter is the date where the loop stops not the number of days or iterations.
so for example

```
date_d = Date.parse( '2010-08-01' )
date_d.step(date_d - 4 , step=-2){|d|
   puts d        
}
```

will output

```
2010-08-01
2010-07-30
2010-07-28
```